# Avoiding duplicate modules in bundles when using npm for front-end projects

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, browserify

Npm allows several versions of the same package to be used in a project. This is a powerful feature.

However in most front-end projects, I would argue that it is not desired to have dependencies on the same library in different versions.

Having dependencies on the same library in different versions means, that the end-user would have to load the given library several times (as seperate requests or as part of a bigger bundle).

However if npm is used to manage dependencies of a frontend-project, you can end up very quickly with dependencies on the same library in different versions.

I think in most cases this is undesired and most of the time we are not even aware of the situation.

A simple case where we end up in such a situation:

At some point in time you install `react-router` and `history` in your project:

```
npm i -S react-router@1.0.0-rc1
npm i -S history@1.17.0
```

At that time `react-router` has a dependency to `history@1.17.0`. As a result your project as a whole has only a dependency to this version of `history`.

Later you decide to upgrade to the latest version of `react-router`:

```
npm i -S react-router@2
```

Now `react-router` has a dependency on `history@2`.

**As a consequence your project has now a dependency on `history@1.17.0` and a transitive dependency on `history@2`.**

Both versions of `history` are included in your `npm_modules`.

If your are using a module bundler like Webpack or Browerify, you end up with a bundle that contains both versions of `history`.

Most probably you don't notice. But if you would notice, you would probably upgrade your direct dependency to `history@2.

How can we deal with this problem?

**How can we find out if our front-end project has dependencies on the same library in different versions?**

**How can we avoid ending up with bundles that are bigger than they should be?**

I know that technically npm/Webpack/Browserify are correct in including dependencies on the same library in different versions in a bundle. But I am looking for a way to make it easily visible that this is happening, so that the developer can take steps to optimize the dependencies.

I also recreated the example in this repo: https://github.com/jbandi/npm-package-problems

Answer (score 1):

The [find-duplicate-dependencies](https://github.com/wizardzloy/find-duplicate-dependencies) tool can be used to examine a `node_modules` directory and report upon packages that are present with multiple versions.

I guess it makes some sense to tackle the problem at a `node_modules`-level, as doing so works in both WebPack and Browserify situations.

Comment: I tried `find-duplicate-dependencies`on a non-trivial project and its very hard to make sense of all the output it reports. I think the main problem is that we also have dev-dependencies managed via npm. And there duplicate transitive dependencies are not really an issue.

It would be nice if `find-duplicate-dependencies` could be scoped to dependencies only, ignoring dev-dependencies.

Comment: Also it seems that `find-duplicate-dependencies` is not a widely used tool (and not under active development). I am wondering how other projects are dealing with this problem... Why is there not a "state-of-the-art" solution i.e. mentioned in some of the Webpack tutorials out there?

Comment: Your points are all valid and I agree with you. Some time ago, I wrote my own tool to parse and analyse my Browserify bundles. After reading your question, I was thinking there'd have to be some merit in analysing `node_modules` instead and a quick search found that tool. If nothing else, perhaps it's a starting point? Hopefully, somebody else has already done it.